# Convert v-model value from number to string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `<q-select>` component and inside that i'm sending options that i fetch from API, as value I set id of object, but problem is that it expects string to get and ID is a number and because of that I'm getting error.
Is it possible to change type of data inside `v-model`.

```
<s-select
  autocomplete
  sorted
  v-model="data.id"
  options="list"
  option-value="value"
  option-label="label"
  label="Field"
  required
 />
```

I've tried to put `data.id.toString()` inside v-model but then I got error.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `computed method` with a getter/setter defined.

```
computed: {
 computedDataId: {
  get() {
    return this.data.id.toString()
  },
  set(val) {
    this.data.id = Number(val)
  }
 }
}
```

And then use the computed method as the model

```
<s-select
  autocomplete
  sorted
  v-model="computedDataId"
  options="list"
  option-value="value"
  option-label="label"
  label="Field"
  required
 />
```

You can also consider converting `data.id` to a string when getting it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply the method to `v-model`. One solution would be converting the `id` to `string` directly after fetching the data as follows:

```
let id = data.id;
data.id = id.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <s-select
   autocomplete
   sorted
   :value="data.id.toString()"
   options="list"
   option-value="value"
   option-label="label"
   label="Field"
   required
  />
```

Comment: This will only update the s-select from data source, but won't update data source.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a computed property for that

```
computed: {
 id: {
   return String(this.data.id);
 }
}
```

Your template will be cleaner and stays reactive

```
<s-select
  autocomplete
  sorted
  v-model="id"
  options="list"
  option-value="value"
  option-label="label"
  label="Field"
  required
 />
```